# How To Show Loading Animation After Click Submit Form?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, onclick, loading

I have a problem in execution time of my report generation using php. In order to make user can know that script still running, I want to add simple loading.gif after click submit form.
This is the scheme of my script:

**form.html**

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="do.php" target="_new">
    <input type="text" name="param1">
    <input type="text" name="param2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So, basically user firstly input parameter for generating report they wanted. And then their parameter will be send to php script [do.php] for next process (generate report).
And this is php script of [do.php]:

**do.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #loadingdiv {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background:url(load50.gif) no-repeat center center #FFF;
                position: fixed;
            }
        </style>";
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function swapdiv() { 
                if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
                    document.getElementById('loadingdiv').style.display = 'none'; 
                }else { 
                    if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
                        document.loadingdiv.display = 'none'; 
                    }else { // IE 4 
                        document.all.loadingdiv.style.display = 'none'; 
                    } 
                } 
                if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
                    document.getElementById('resultdiv').style.display = 'block'; 
                } else { 
                    if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
                        document.resultdiv.display = 'block'; 
                    } else { // IE 4 
                        document.all.resultdiv.style.display = 'block'; 
                    } 
                } 
                window.onunload = null;
                return;
            } 
        </script>";
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='loadingdiv' align='center'></div>
        <div id='resultdiv' style='display:none;'>
            <?php
            include "search_process.php";
            ?>
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            //this is called after page loaded
            window.onload=swapdiv;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I had did add script to show loading.gif animation when do.php executed. But, loading.gif only appear when php script execution status in browser was transferring data... when it's status was waiting response... loading.gif not appear.

**What I wanted is when user click submit form then loading.gif appear even do.php status still waiting response**. I'll be glad to hear any solution from all of you kind people :)

Thanks.

Comment: When you submit a form, the page reloads ?

Comment: When user click submit form, then it open new tab for do.php . What i wanted is when do.php executed in new tab, then it will show loading.gif until query/report html finished created.